# How do I unlock a tuple after updating in MySQL/Innodb?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I am trying to model a transaction database for my databases course. I can't find how to unlock a tuple after using it for update.

I have used commits and assumed that this would release the exclusive lock but it doesn't.

```sql
START TRANSACTION;
BEGIN;
SELECT * FROM account WHERE account_num = 3 FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE account SET balance= balance + 100 WHERE account_num = 3;
COMMIT;
```

What am I supposed to do to make sure this exclusive lock is let go?

Comment: Where/How do you see that exclusive lock?

Comment: `COMMIT` should release row locks whether you acquired them with `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` or `UPDATE`. I think you must be seeing some other effect, like you have multiple sessions going at the same time, and you haven't committed in all the sessions.

Answer (score 0):

`START TRANSACTION` and `BEGIN` are synonyms; don't use both.

Unless you are doing something else in the transaction, there is no need for the `SELECT`, nor for the transaction.  `UPDATE` will lock the row for the duration of the `UPDATE`.